# MVC Populating Dropdown from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

New to MVC trying to populate a dropdown from Database, proving a bit more tricky than I imagined.

Here's what I have.

```
public class EmployeeDetailsModel
{
    public string SelectedEmployee { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult MiEmployeeDetails()
{
  var model = new EmployeeDetailsModel();
  model.Employees = _db.geo_employees.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
   {
      Value = x.name,
      Text = x.name
   });

   return View(model);
}
```

View

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedEmployee, (SelectList) Model.Employees) %>
```

But getting the error

> CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not cast your `IEnumerable` to the `SelectList` - you need to create a new instance of it:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedEmployee, new SelectList(Model.Employees)) %>
```

**Update.** While the comment above holds, the actual problem turned out to be dynamically typed view. Such views do not allow use of lambdas in helpers, such as `x => x.SelectedEmployee` in question. So the actual solution to the problem was making view strogly typed:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Namespace.EmployeeDetailsModel>
```

Comment: Still getting An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Comment: @StevieB, is your view strongly typed?

Comment: Dynamic I think, Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>"

Comment: I'm more familiar with Razor views, but shouldn't "dynamic" be replaced with YourNamespace.EmployeeDetailsModel?

Comment: @StevieB, then this is another problem. Make it strongly typed with `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Namespace.EmployeeDetailsModel>"`. And for note - it is the lambda `x => x.SelectedEmployee` that causes the error you see. Comment for `SelectList` still holds though

Answer (score 0):

Because `Employees` is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, you don't need to cast it or create a `new SelectList()`, you can just use it directly.

Also I suspect you are missing a `.ToList()`

```
public ActionResult MiEmployeeDetails()
{
  var model = new EmployeeDetailsModel();
  model.Employees = _db.geo_employees.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
   {
      Value = x.name,
      Text = x.name
   }).ToList();

   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Tried just using it directly, i.e. <%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedEmployee, Model.Employees) %> but getting error Extension Method cannot be dynamically dispatched.

Comment: @sgrassie ToList is already in there. The First one should be removed.

Comment: Did you add the ```.ToList()```?

Comment: @bnem yeah I noticed that just before you posted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

ToList should be moved to the end of the statement:

```
model.Employees = _db.geo_employees.Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
   Value = x.name,
   Text = x.name
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Tried this but no change, still getting An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation. Any changes needed on view ?

Comment: Did you try doing new SelectList(Model.Employees) also, instead of (SelectList)Model.Employees?